# Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/generated/.yo-rc.json'

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, yo

I'm a begginer using ubuntu, i'm trying to generate an application, but after launching it i get the following error, i've tried all the solutions proposed on the forum but nothing worked for me.
[here's the shown error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF59e.png)
My operating system is ubuntu 18.04.
Thank you guys!!

Comment: If the file is auto-generated by project, delete file and run your commands, project should create and problem probably will be solved. Otherwise just try to use sudo with your comment. (Generally this is not recommended to use for this kind of stuff.)

Comment: First thing, you do `ls -l /generated/.yo-rc.json` to see who owns that file. That's a yo generator created file, and my guess is, you install yo globally with sudo. So it will be own my root. From that point on, you need to run all your command with sudo. A better way is to remove your yo, setup your npm without sudo, just google "npm without sudo" plenty of answers. Then reinstall your yo globally, and you shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, i looked for the file it doesnt even exist.